# How to load a single 32 bit floating-point into all eight positions within an AVX ymm register?

Tags: c++, optimization, avx

How do I load/convert a single 32 bit floating-point into an AVX 256 ymm register so that all 8 floats are from the single source float?

Previously I used a AVX 128 xmm register to load a single float into 4 packed floats.

```
    movss    xmm7,[eax];
    shufps   xmm7,xmm7,0;

    add eax, 0x4;
```

Answer (score 13):

This operation is sometimes called "broadcasting". AVX has a bunch of instructions doing just that, these are `vbroadcast128`, `vbroadcastsd` and `vbroadcastss`. Since you want to broadcast a single single-precision floating-point value, you want the last of these:

```
vbroadcastss ymm7, [eax]
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want to use a temporary memory location just for broadcasting a value across all of the register's locations, you may consider doing something like that :

```
shufps      xmm0, xmm0, 0
vinsertf128 ymm0, ymm0, xmm0, 1
```

It is assumed that `xmm0` contains the scalar value in the lowest dword of the register at the beginning. `shufps`, when used with 0 as the immediate operand, copies the lowest dword to all the positions of the XMM register. `vinsertf128` then replaces the higher xmmword of the YMM register with the lower xmmword.

I haven't checked which version is actually faster. You're best off testing that yourself in your own application. If you ask me, it totally sucks that there isn't a `vbroadcast` with a register operand.